# Microsoft SQL Server Standard High Availability without Shared Storage

Tags: sql-server, database, high-availability, database-administration

I'm a software dev with little experience managing SQL so please bear with me!

We are developing a piece of software that needs to be highly available, with a significant degree of resilience.
This application will use SQL server to store much of its operational data.

This application will be running from 2 separate physical locations and no shared disk (SANs or whatnot) is allowed between these 2 locations, shared SMB is a possibility but not well liked by our security people.

This application wont commit loads of data to SQL, but there will be 26 instances of this system deployed in the real world, 52 SQL server instances all together so to cut costs we are pretty sure SQL standard is as expensive as we can afford!!!!

What are my options, since DBase mirroring seems to be being obsoleted in the not too distant future?[image: Basic Application Model]

Comment: Why do you need 52 instances of SQL when there are only 2 physical locations? 4 SQL instances, 2 @ each site set up in HA won't do?

Comment: @TravisStoll: I would imagine they have different customers who do not want to share a server/SQL Instance.

Comment: @BartDeVos Is correct, the instances are not aware of one another   by design, also i should clarify for TravisStoll that the 2 computer rooms (physical locations) are per site not in total.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use AlwaysOn.

AlwaysOn is the 'new' way to do this, and the reason DB mirroring is becoming obsolete in SQL Server.

It basically works like this:

[image]

You need to create a Windows Cluster for the Networking-aspect. Shared storage is not needed, but you will need a file-share for the instances to sync the logs (only DB's in FULL recovery can be used) and for Quorum in the cluster (if you have only 2 nodes).

When you set them up in Synchronous Commit, you can have a near online fail-over. You can write your application to handle the small interference. (fail once? => try again)

With SQL 2014 STD, you can set up AlwaysOn for 2 nodes. In Windows 2012 Failover Clustering is also in the standard edition.

Answer (score 0):

As Bart De Vos mentioned, you can use **SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Groups** (which does'nt require a SAN) but this feature is only available in the **Enterprise** edition.

Alternatevily you can use **SQL Server AlwaysOn Failover Cluster** which is present in the **Standard** edition. But AlwaysOn Cluster requires a SAN, however you can simulate one using 3rd party software, like SIOS DataKeeper.

For more information please refer to the folowing links:
http://clusteringformeremortals.com/2014/01/10/creating-a-sql-server-2014-alwayson-failover-cluster-fci-instance-in-windows-azure-iaas-azure-cloud/

http://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2013/02/04/step-by-step-building-a-windows-server-2012-failover-cluster-study-lab-in-the-cloud-with-windows-azure.aspx